# Background image of element flickering during CSS transition in webkit

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm having an issue where I have a CSS transition on my page (the header shrinks when you scroll down) and while the transition is occurring the background image of another element is flickering/shaking in webkit (Firefox is perfect). I've seen that people have had similar issues and I've tried the many different solutions offered out there such as adding:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

But have had no luck.

You can see an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ojdavey/9sesxy0y.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No flickering here. Version 43.0.2357.81 m, Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: Now that I fiddled around with it for a while, I think I see what you mean. The whole shrinking animation doesn't feel smooth but rather quite jerky. I assume it would help alot if you reduce animation duration drastically.

Comment: The speed is a bit irrelevant, I made it 3.6s just to show the issue. I've changed it back to 0.6s and you can still see the issue.

Comment: transform:translate3d(0,0,0); made it smoother for me (Chrome OS X). There is still subpixel rounding as the transition comes to an end, but the shakiness you describe is noticeably reduced (to my eye, at least).

Comment: I added this in. Doesn't really look much better though :s